# Rewrite url - Rediriger sans index.php

Tags: .htaccess, web, url-rewriting

my URL is of the type: www.mysite.fr and for any page: www.mysite.fr/index.php/test

I wish that www.mysite.fr/test displays www.mysite.fr/index.php/test (it's more beautiful without index.php!)

I tried this but: www.mysite.fr/test displays the home page instead of the test page

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
 
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,7}\s/(.*)index\.php/(.*)\sHTTP.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Second line to remove `index.php` exteranlly.

Fifth line to redirect request to original path internally .

**Note:** clear browser cache the test

Comment: Thanks but it works in localhost only. The website displays "file not found"

Comment: does .htaccess in main root?

Answer (score 0):

Your method works on my localhost but not on my online site. This is the 5th line that blocks in my opinion but I do not see why even adding a slash before index.
Someone have an idea ?